# Raycaster display a Render

Tags: reactjs, three.js, raycasting

I use Threejs and I would like to create a function to display a descriptive card (**Render()** of **Satllite.js**) when I click on a Sphere. (**Satellite.js**)

```
/********** Imports **********/
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';

import satData from '../data/sat.json';

export class Satellites extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { open: true }

    this.x = {};
    this.mouse = {};
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

  }

  onDocumentMouseDown = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1
    // find intersections
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.props.camera)
    this.intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(
      this.scene.className("card"),
      false
    )
    if (this.intersects.length > 0) {
      if (this.intersects[0].object.callback)
        this.intersects[0].object.callback()
      this.intersects[0].className(".card")

      this.particle = new THREE.Sprite(this.particleMaterial)
      this.particle.position.copy(this.intersects[0].point)

      this.particle.scale.x = this.particle.scale.y = 16
      this.props.scene.add(this.particle)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Satellite Sphere
    // this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( this.props.data.r, 32, 32 );
    this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32)
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 })
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material)
    this.sphere.callback = function() {
      console.log('Toto!')
    }
    this.sphere.position.set(50, 50, 50)
    this.props.scene.add(this.sphere)
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDocumentMouseDown, true)
  }

  // componentDidUpdate() {
  //   // update satelite pos.
  //   const radius = 10;
  //   const scale = radius * 1;
  //   this.sphere.scale.x = scale;
  //   this.sphere.scale.y = scale;
  //   this.sphere.scale.z = scale;
  // }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onDocumentMouseDown);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {satData.map((satDetail, index) => {
          return <div key={index} className="card">
            <h2>{satDetail.satName.toUpperCase()}</h2>
            <div className="cardImg" >
              <img src={satDetail.satImg} alt={satDetail.satAlt} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Altitude : <span>{satDetail.alt}</span> km</p>
              <p>Longitude : <span>{satDetail.long}</span> °</p>
              <p>Latitude : <span>{satDetail.lat}</span> °</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Fermer</button>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

More details [here](https://github.com/SolenneD/earth-react)

I got the code of a tutorial that show white squares but I would like to display **my div ".card"** which is in the **"Render"**
What is the method ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer involves many topics combined, basically you need:

1. Raycast the mouse click and find the object intersection,
2. Get info by picked object,
3. Display it if object was selected, or hide if nothing was picked by mouse.

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/9k4qbL8s/

```js
let cardShown = false;

function showCard(userText) {
  var divElement = $("#card");

  if (divElement) {
    if (!cardShown) {
      divElement.css({
        display: "block",
        opacity: 0,
        height: "0px"
      });
    }

    divElement.text("Object color: " + userText);

        if (!cardShown) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        divElement.css({
          opacity: 1,
          height: "16px"
        });
      }, 25);
    }

    cardShown = true;
  }
}

function hideCard() {
  var divElement = $("#card");
  if (divElement) {
    divElement.css({
      height: "0px",
      opacity: 0
    });
    cardShown = false;
  }
}

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

//create some camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 5;
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.position.z = 5;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x595959));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// white spotlight shining from the side, casting a shadow
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 2.5, 25, Math.PI / 6);
spotLight.position.set(4, 10, 7);
scene.add(spotLight);

// collect objects for raycasting, 
// for better performance don't raytrace all scene
var clickableObjects = [];

var colors = new RayysWebColors();
for (let k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
  var size = 0.5;
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, 0.2, size);
  var randomColor = colors.pickRandom();
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: randomColor.hex,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.75
  });
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.userData.userText = randomColor.name;
  cube.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(k % 3, 0, Math.floor(k / 3) - 1));
  scene.add(cube);
  clickableObjects.push(cube);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// this will be 2D coordinates of the current mouse position, [0,0] is middle of the screen.
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

var clickedObj; // this objects is hovered at the moment

// Following two functions will convert mouse coordinates
// from screen to three.js system (where [0,0] is in the middle of the screen)
function updateMouseCoords(event, coordsObj) {
  coordsObj.x = ((event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft + 0.5) / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  coordsObj.y = -((event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop + 0.5) / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  updateMouseCoords(event, mouse);

  latestMouseProjection = undefined;
  clickedObj = undefined;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera); {
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(clickableObjects);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      latestMouseProjection = intersects[0].point;
      clickedObj = intersects[0].object;
      showCard(clickedObj.userData.userText);
    } else {
      clickedObj = undefined;
      hideCard();
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);

animate();
```

Comment: Thanks, this jsfiddle helped me a lot !